# Open game in Cemu emulator from C# script

Tags: c#

I want to open a CEMU game (Wii U emulation) with code in C#.
I've tried:

```
Process.Start($"<Path to Cemu>\Cemu.exe", "<Path to file>");
```

It opens Cemu, but it doesn't load the game in. So any ideas?

Comment: That looks like it should work just fine. Cemu might require the argument in a certain format

Comment: Does your file path have any spaces and/or need to be quoted?

Comment: It doesn't have spaces and it is quoted, but I think it's right that it needs a certain format. I just don't know which.